# Where did this question go wrong?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/153532/how-to-deal-with-bad-developers-who-hold-back-the-project

I suppose that it could have gone on [Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/faq) (I didn't realize that site existed until it was commented on) but considering the list of questions in the related questions list, it seemed OK.

Where did this question go wrong? It seems like once a down vote occurs, they flood in and you're toast!

Is it possible to move it to workplace if it isn't appropriate for Programmers?

Comment: Don't worry about the down votes, they'll go away if the question is migrated or deleted. Also prepare for more votes (up/down), that's normal when bringing up a question on Meta.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, thank you for not cross posting on The Workplace. I've written [a rant](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3701/25936) recently on how to get a question migrated there, the gist of it is:

> 1. Flag for moderation attention, or
> 2. Drop the questions in the [Water Cooler](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler), the Workplace's main chat room.

For the question in question I'd go with option 2, asking in the Water Cooler. It's a bit lonely in there, but *if* there's a version of your question that fits The Workplace, the regulars will guide you to it.

As for why it's not a good fit for Programmers, well as always, the [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) puts it best:

> Please make sure your question uniquely applies to programmers in general:
>
> [image]

Your question is about a *people* problem, not a software development problem, and that the people involved happen to be programmers doesn't make it unique to our profession.

Comment: Ok thanks. I put it up in the water-cooler as suggested. Maybe it can be moved before I get down to 1 rep.

Comment: Can it just be deleted?

Comment: looks like someone migrated it.

Comment: @ILovePaperTowels See, the system works!