# Auto recommend the correct site for a question

Tags: feature-request, migration

With my recent question issue  (see [Where did this question go wrong?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3709/where-did-this-question-go-wrong))
 it seems like a nice feature for users would be to auto suggest the correct site for a question. This could happen any number of ways, but I would think a quick and dirty implementation would use the tags the user has decided to use.

For example, my question was apparently better suited for workplace. I used the people-management tag. If people management type of questions are not suitable for P.SE it would have been helpful (since I didn't know about workplace initially) for P.SE to suggest, "Hey, you're using a tag that might make your question off-topic for this site. Maybe XYZ would be a better choice?".

Just my thoughts. I realize it could be a huge job, but could help new users and anyone who isn't familiar with the 50 SE sites that are available.

Comment: Related: [Should we mention The Workplace in our FAQ?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3632/should-we-mention-the-workplace-in-our-faq)

Answer (score 4):

This wouldn't really be possible because sites overlap to some degree so some question may fit many sites. Furthermore sites shouldn't have tags that cannot contain any on topic questions, programmers is a bit of a mess with tags because the SE definition of the site and the user definition of the site weren't always in sync, and there are also a lot of general topics that specific subsets are acceptable which is also a bit of an exception.

The best way to determine if a question is on topic is to read the [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq). If you do receive comments that another site may be better simply flag your post and ask it to be considered for migration. Don't feel to bad about posting an off topic question, thats why closing and deleting are separate, or not being aware of site X, just learn from it and the community will generally help you with that and also try to get questions to places where they will do the most good for everyone.

Comment: I do agree that the sites overlap in various aspects, but I still think that something like this might be useful. Instead of suggesting 'hey, your question belongs here' why not have a 'You used tag X, and that tag is also popular on the following Stack Exchange sites'?